# Listening to onSelect events from Autocomplete (Primefaces) component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to listen to `select` event from autocomplete using attribute `selectListener`.
I am passing a `remoteCommand` as select listener. But the `selectListener` never calls this `remoteCommand` method.

My code follows:

```
<h:form>
    <p:autoComplete autocomplete="true" completeMethod="#{search.fetchSuggestions}" value="#{search.selectedSuggestion}" selectListener="moveToSelectedPage()"/>

    <p:remoteCommand name="moveToSelectedPage" action="firstPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
</h:form>
```

All I am trying to do is, navigating to a different page after the user selects a particular suggested item among suggestions made by autocomplete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `selectListener` attribute should refer to a managed bean method taking `SelectEvent` and returning `void`, not to some arbitrary JavaScript function.

See also the [PrimeFaces `<p:autoComplete>` showcase page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteSelect.jsf).

```
<p:autoComplete selectListener="#{autoCompleteBean.handleSelect}" ... />
```

with

```
public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Looking at PrimeFaces version 3.5, it appears that the `selectListener` attribute is no longer available for the AutoComplete component.  The link in BalusC's answer leads to the correct place, where it shows the new approach to be to include a `<p:ajax>` tag inside the `<p:autocomplete>`:

```
<p:autoComplete id="acSimple" value="#{autoCompleteBean.txt1}" completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.complete}">  
  <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{autoCompleteBean.handleSelect}" update="messages" />  
</p:autoComplete>
```